# What info is needed to calculate AAA battery life?

Tags: alkaline

I have a flashlight that uses (9) 10mA white light diodes and they are placed 8 in a circle and 1 in the middle. The flashlight is powered by (3) 1.5v AAA batteries. 
**(Here are the the battery details)**

Battery Type Alkaline Long-life

Avg. voltage During discharge-1.225

milli-Amp hours(mAh)-1150

Watt-hours Wh-1.41

Joules-5071

**Question-**
**How many hours should the batteries last?** I'm at 102 continuous hrs so far, I am running a test using a secondary catalyst that I believe will prolong the battery's life span, the catalyst does not have any electrical value or been proposed to increase the lifespan of batteries.I will keep you updated but I cannot give any information to my catalyst or theory sorry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are lithium, so they do not like being discharged fully, I don't know if this is only with Lithium-Polymer or just Lithium batteries all together, you can work it out by finding the combined capacity of all 3 cells.

Comment: I am at 78 continuous hours so far. Normal?

Comment: Thats pretty impressive it must be a low watt LED, any idea what the wattage is of the flashlight?

Comment: At least two informations are missing: capacity of the battery, power drawn from it. If you have that, read one of the million other questions that tell you how to calculate these things

Comment: Are the batteries wired in parallel or series? Are the LEDs in parallel or series? Is there any electronics, ie some sort of boost circuit in the torch? You really need to give more information. I´ve seen 1000mAH AAA lithium batteries, so with a low draw, eg 5mA-10mA, you could get 100 hours of use before the batteries start to die.

Comment: its your basic cheap dollar store flashlight and the batteries are generic also, that's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: the light diodes are placed 8 in a circle and 1 in the center

Answer (score 2):

Battery capacities are usually specified in milliampere-hours, or mAh. You don't say what the capacity of your batteries are, but you can usually find it in the manufacturer's datasheet.

You also need to know the current draw of the LEDs. For a typical LED, such as the one in your picture, it's about 15mAh typically. This is probably reasonable for a cheap keychain flashlight. More expensive flashlights have brighter LEDs which require more current.

Calculating the run time is then just a matter of dimensional analysis. Let's just assume your batteries have a capacity of 1000mAh:

$$ \require{cancel}
{1000\:\mathrm{\cancel{mA}h} \over 1} \cdot
{1 \over 15\:\mathrm{\cancel{mA}}} =
66.6\:\text{hours}
$$

Comment: Can you recalculate the life with the new info provided so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to predict this. It depends on how much current your load (the LEDs) draws.  And it depends on the capacity of the power source (the AAA cells).

Furthermore, not all AAA cells are the same. So just because you get xxx hours from one set of batteries doesn't mean that a different brand (or chemistry) of cell (or even the same cells from the same brand but a different batch) will give you the same results.  It's not as simple as that.

Different brands and different chemistries of AAA cells have a wide range of capacity. They range from well under 500 mAh to well over 1000 mAh.  And we have not the slightest clue how much your LEDs draw without actually measuring them. And we also don't know at what voltage level the LEDs quit producing light.

Comment: were going to say 10 mA, so should another 24hrs be the limit?

Comment: sorry I had to add the correct info